# Ltrim trimming extra character

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below code:

```
SELECT
    ltrim('REASON_ACTIVE_DCA', 'REASON_') reason
FROM
    dual
```

However, I'm obtaining '_CTIVE_DCA'. What's happening and how can I get 'ACTIVE_DCA' with ltrim?

Comment: You are asking to do something **with LTRIM**. In most cases that doesn't make sense; "with LTRIM" may or may not be a way to do what you need to do, but it should not be included in the requirement. What you need to do is to remove REASON_ from the front of the string; **how** you do that is not a requirement. (Unless, that is, you are learning about LTRIM and you want to see specifically how to do it with LTRIM and in no other way.)

Comment: I know how to do it with regexp, my question was more like if it was possible with ltrim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `LTRIM()` removes all the characters *as a set*.  So all leading "R"s and "E"s and so on removed.  In fact, the *ordering* of the characters in the second string is irrelevant, so you would get the same result with `'_NOSAER'`.

If you want to remove the leading string of `REASON_` -- if present -- then you don't use `trim()`.  Instead, one method is:

```
select (case when 'REASON_ACTIVE_DCA' LIKE 'REASON$_%' ESCAPE '$'
             then substr('REASON_ACTIVE_DCA', 8)
             else 'REASON_ACTIVE_DCA'
        end)
```

There are other ways, such as:

```
select regexp_replace('REASON_ACTIVE_DCA', '^REASON_', '')
```

Comment: What do you mean 'all the characters as a set'? I did not understand that bit.

Comment: In the first solution you are missing a `%` in the `LIKE` comparison.

Comment: @jeiv The point is ltrim doesn't trim the string 'REASON_', it trims any of the seven characters listed. `ltrim('SONY','REASON_')` would leave `'Y'`, for example, because 'S', 'O' and 'N' are in the set of characters to trim.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson oh, I understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with regular string functions (not regular expressions), and using `INSTR` instead of `LIKE` so I don't have to worry about escaping underscore.

Something like this - including a few sample strings in the `WITH` clause for testing:

```
with
  inputs (i_str) as (
    select 'REASON_ACTIVE_DCA' from dual union all
    select 'REASON_NOT_GIVEN'  from dual union all
    select null                from dual union all
    select 'REASON-SPECIAL'    from dual union all
    select 'REASON_'           from dual union all
    select 'REASON'            from dual
  )
select i_str, substr(i_str, case instr(i_str, 'REASON_') 
                                 when 1 then 1 + length('REASON_')
                                 else        1   end) as new_str
from   inputs;

I_STR             NEW_STR          
----------------- -----------------
REASON_ACTIVE_DCA ACTIVE_DCA       
REASON_NOT_GIVEN  NOT_GIVEN        
                                   
REASON-SPECIAL    REASON-SPECIAL   
REASON_                            
REASON            REASON
```